# Flow type does not apply to outer scope variables within an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, flowtype

I have a type defined for an action dispatched to a reducer:

```
type RemoveQuestionAction = {
  type: 'REMOVE_QUESTION',
  questionId: number,
  docTypeId: number,
};

type QuestionAction =
  | RemoveQuestionAction
  | ...
```

The reducer checks the type of each action:

```
const questions = (
  state : QuestionState = defaultState,
  action : QuestionAction
) : QuestionState => {...};
```

The field `questionId` is referenced in a couple of array filters:

```
  case REMOVE_QUESTION: {

    return {
      ...state,
      byId: state.allIds
                             // Throws error
        .filter(id => id !== action.questionId)
        .reduce((col, id) => ({
          ...col,
          [id]: state.byId[String(id)],
        }), {}),
                                               // Throws error
      allIds: state.allIds.filter(id => id !== action.questionId),
    };    
  }
```

This throws a type error for `action.questionId`.

However if the value from the action is placed in a variable, it is happy:

```
  case REMOVE_QUESTION: {
    let { questionId } = action; // Ok with this

    return {
      ...state,
      byId: state.allIds
        .filter(id => id !== questionId)
        .reduce((col, id) => ({
          ...col,
          [id]: state.byId[String(id)],
        }), {}),
      allIds: state.allIds.filter(id => id !== questionId),
    };    
  }
```

Why can't I use the `action`'s value directly?

Here is a [REPL](https://flow.org/try/#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-WGzOm81CMBWm00h3ImZZqO7HiuoR4KCMYgG8QisXFFVxHjRdAez4aENCmsicRmACMOacyccUvMVX3VXjobPbg8YCqZLw-DgIyr2pMAXE+5LK9d0ULJwKmqOomlaDpuj6AZhlGEwByKWYfyFZZVnWRDdHzGIgA).

It performs as expected in the REPL, really strange as I can't see what could be different..

Flow is version 6.23

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this. Can you put together a REPL on Flow.org that demonstrates this problem? My test works as expected (unfortunately I can't link to it since the URL is too long for a comment, and SO doesn't allow URLs from shorteners.

Comment: It might be related to refinement invalidations. https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements Which versions of flow are you using?

Comment: @ShuheiKagawa It could be, but I don't understand why the version in the REPL would behave that way

Comment: The REPL works because `QuestionAction` has only one type. `type QuestionAction =
  | RemoveQuestionAction
  | { type: 'FOO' }` will give you an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`action.questionId` throws an error because of refinement invalidation explained in [the doc for type refinement](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/). Flow is not sure whether `action` is still `RemoveQuestionAction` or not when the arrow functions that are given to `filter()` are executed after the refinement by `case REMOVE_QUESTION:`.

We humans know that `filter()` **immediately** executes the given callback function like `id => id !== action.questionId` so that `action` cannot be modified at all. However, from flow's perspective, `filter()` is just a function that takes a callback function as an argument, and the callback function **can be** executed later like what `addEventListener()` does. If the callback function can be executed later, there is a chance that `action` is modified and the type refinement no longer holds. That's why flow invalidates the type refinement of `action` in such a case.